# Cannot resolve interface defined in the same module but in different file

Tags: module, namespaces, typescript, typescript1.7

Below the code

fields/base.ts

```
/// <reference path="../_all.ts" />

module SomeApp.fields {
  export interface IField {}
  export class Field implements IFields {}
}
```

in fields/CharField.ts

```
/// <reference path="../_all.ts" />

module SomeApp.fields {

  import IField = SomeApp.fields.IField; 

  export interface ICharField extends IField {}
  export class Field implements IFields {}
}
```

in _all.ts:

```
/// <reference path="fields/base.ts" />
/// <reference path="fields/CharField.ts" />
```

but this does not work, and I got this error from `CharField.ts` file:

> Error:(7, 39) TS2305: Module 'SomeApp.fields' has no exported member
>   'IField'.

So what's wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem raises a few questions:

1. How are you compiling this?
2. Wy is _all.ts a .ts file and not a .d.ts file?
3. Why are you importing IField (depends on point "1")?

Here is a working example:

```
.
+-- tsconfig.json
+-- references.d.ts
+--  src
|   +-- myInterface.ts
|   +-- myClass.ts
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "out": "result.js",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "files": [
        "src/myClass.ts"
    ]
}
```

references.d.ts:

```
/// <reference path="src/myInterface.ts" />
/// <reference path="src/myClass.ts" />
```

myInterface.ts:

```
module MyNameSpace {

    export interface IMyInterface {
        // ...
    }
}
```

myClass.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../references.d.ts" />

module MyNameSpace {
    export class MyClass implements IMyInterface {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The example above works, exactly why your example does not work might be to any of the 1, 2, or 3 points mentioned above.